# MYSQL: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''

Tags: mysql

i am getting this error:

```
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ''"
```

with the following query:

```
update `mod_service_details` set `status` = 'Validating', `updated_at` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where `serviceid` = 5180
```

to me that looks like valid SQL. Does anyone know why it would be giving such an error?

Comment: Please share the schema for the table mod_service_details

Comment: A [mre] should indeed include the schema for the table.